# var_dump prints to screen before prepended elements

Tags: php, var-dump

Why does PHP's `var_dump()` print fist when I make it the second element of a concatenated string?

```
echo  "log_files: " . var_dump($log_files);

=> array (size=4)
      0 => string '.' (length=1)
      1 => string '..' (length=2)
      2 => string 'non_ssl_log.txt' (length=35)
      3 => string 'ssl_access_log.txt' (length=31)
   log_files:
```

And how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "log file : \n";
var_dump($log_files);
```

as for reason why its doing it no clue sorry.

Comment: also possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364232/why-do-print-r-and-var-dump-execute-before-echo