# PHP output wrong way around

Tags: php, echo, var-dump

Hopefully a simple one to replicate (assuming it's not my setup...)

I have the following in a PHP script:

```
echo('$userID:&emsp;' . var_dump($userID) . '<br>');
echo('$hashValidate:&emsp;' . var_dump($hashValidate) . '<br>');
```

The output is showing as:

> bool(false) $userID:
>   bool(false) $hashValidate:

---

Shouldn't it be this way around though?

> $userID:   bool(false)
>   $hashValidate: bool(false)

Comment: Nope, that is correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364232/why-do-print-r-and-var-dump-execute-before-echo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. `var_dump()` performs IMMEDIATE output, and has no return value. That means your code is running the same as if you had

```
var_dump($var)
echo('$userID:&emsp;<br>');
```

You'd need this instead:

```
echo '$userID:'
var_dump(...);
echo '<br>';
```

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying - and providing an alternative! I'll accept once the time limit has passed....

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
echo('$userID:&emsp;' . var_export($userID, true) . '<br>');
echo('$hashValidate:&emsp;' . var_export($hashValidate, true) . '<br>');
```

Comment: Lacks the information of MarcB's answer, but this method is arguably cleaner and at least matches more closely OP's expectations.